# How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on multi conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'user': ['user 1', 'user 4', 'user 1', 'user 4', 'user 1', 'user 4'],
                 'group': [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                'x1': [0.9, 0.9, 0.7, 0.7, 0.4, 0.4],
                'x2': [0.759740, 1.106061, 0.619357, 1.260234, 0.540633, 1.437956]})
```

output:

```
    user  group  x1    x2
0   user 1  0   0.9 0.759740
1   user 4  0   0.9 1.106061
2   user 1  1   0.7 0.619357
3   user 4  1   0.7 1.260234
4   user 1  2   0.4 0.540633
5   user 4  2   0.4 1.437956
```

I want to return each user with a condition if x2 is below x1 then return this row and if there is no row that meets this condition when x2 is below x1 then return this user with a change group number to 10.

For example: for the user1, row number 2 should be selected since it returns a min value of x2 below x1 1 and even row 4 has a min value of x2 but x2 is higher than x1. for user 4, all x2 higher than x1 for all rows, so we change group number for min value of x2 to number 10.

[image]

The expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df2 = (df[df['x2'].lt(df['x1'])]
           .set_index('group')
           .groupby('user')['x2']
           .idxmin()
           .reindex(df['user'].unique(), fill_value=10)
           .reset_index(name='group'))
print (df2)

     user  group
0  user 1      1
1  user 4     10
```

**How it working:**

First filter rows by condition in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df[df['x2'].lt(df['x1'])])
     user  group   x1        x2
0  user 1      0  0.9  0.759740
2  user 1      1  0.7  0.619357
```

Then get group names by minimal `x2` per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html), so used [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
print (df[df['x2'].lt(df['x1'])].set_index('group'))
         user   x1        x2
group                       
0      user 1  0.9  0.759740
1      user 1  0.7  0.619357
```

And then add missing users by unique values in [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
print (df[df['x2'].lt(df['x1'])].set_index('group').groupby('user')['x2'].idxmin())
user
user 1     1
Name: x2, dtype: int64

print (df[df['x2'].lt(df['x1'])].set_index('group')
        .groupby('user')['x2'].idxmin()
        .reindex(df['user'].unique(), fill_value=10))
user
user 1     1
user 4    10
Name: x2, dtype: int64
```

And last create 2 columns DataFrame by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html).

Comment: thank you but in output, we should replace (x2) with a group!!

Comment: @alxander21 - oops, you are right, answer was edited. By `.reset_index(name='group')`

Comment: thank you, could we save this series into a dataframe with two columns (user and group)? this is my expected output.

Comment: @alxander21 - answer was edited, now working like need.